# Product Edit SQL Error

Tags: sql

It's been a few days that this error show up when editors editing a product:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ) AND (p.entity_id = '4623') LIMIT 1' at line 3, query was:SELECT DISTINCT p.entity_id FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `p` INNER JOIN `catalog_product_flat_4` AS `cpf` ON cpf.entity_id = p.entity_id LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_product` AS `ccp` ON ccp.product_id = p.entity_id WHERE ( () ) AND (p.entity_id = '4623') LIMIT 1

I suppose it's due to empty WHERE section of sql statement, i'm not sure if editors changed/delete record or something? I roll back database to few days back and check the equal sql statement that works fine and here it is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.entity_id FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `p` INNER JOIN `catalog_product_flat_4` AS `cpf` ON cpf.entity_id = p.entity_id LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_product` AS `ccp` ON ccp.product_id = p.entity_id WHERE ( (`ccp`.`category_id` IN ('68')) ) AND (p.entity_id = '3671') LIMIT 1
```

As you see the part missing from first statement is `ccp`.`category_id` IN ('68') part. I checked the category with id=68 and it still exist.
Any idea what may caused this error?
Also what is interest me is that `ccp`.`category_id` IN ('68')) section is on every product i tried to edit. Although many products not belongs to this category (68). Why magento check that?

Answer (score 0):

Open your **phpmyadmin** and run below **query**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_flat_4`
```

Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: I suppose re-index data would do that (something that i've already done), anyway manual truncate table not working too.

Comment: truncate the table by phpmyadmin options if you not have root acess! Then edit

Comment: I did, not working

Answer (score 0):

Finally i figured it out, for future references:
There was this active "Catalog Price Rules" with empty Category rule (Category is ...), and that caused the error. Thanks to [this post](http://michaelthessel.com/tracking-magento-database-queries/) from michael thessel who helped me track down the issue, very useful post for track which Magento file running the queries.